# Zend framework 2 database relations

Tags: zend-framework2, relational-database

I'm working on a project that requires Zend Framework 2 and I'm new with this.
I'm having issues with the relational functionality between entities.
I have a notice entity and also a category entity. And a Form for the notices creation, and one fieldset for notices and one for categories.
I'm trying to make a CRUD that handles this kind of relations (one to many) and I can't handle it using the example that is on the zend's documentation page.
I don't have time to integrate it with Doctrine. Is there any other solution? Can I handle it this way?

My idea is to have a notice creation/edit form that populates a select element with all the categories. I already made that. But it doesn't save the ID on the category_id field on database.

Any idea? how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt work the obvious way right now. Either use Doctrine on check here
https://bitbucket.org/latterd/smodels/src/d86fb6905123/vendor/Supa?at=master

This might be not the clean approach but it works. The best way is to use doctrine or create you own hack